# Integrating a defined function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

If I have this equation:

```
classes = x^2
```

Is it possible to integrate it with the name of the function as the argument,
in other words i am trying trying to do this:

```
Integrate[classes]
```

and i know I have to include the integration variable but I'm not sure what the second argument has to be

Comment: `Integrate[classes, x]`. Did you read the documentation for `Integrate` at all? :P

Comment: Yes and they only give examples with the variables in the arguments

Comment: It is more robust (safer) to define `classes` with `classes[x_] := x^2` and follow the documentation examples. Why don't you want to do it that way?